# Question on element alignment and how cursor is able to stay flush with the text in this editable code textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aktorou/pen/YWxorK), most of it I grok. But a couple of things I don't understand:

1. How does the `<code>` element stay perfectly on top of the `<textarea>`?  I would expect it to be below the textarea looking at the HTML code.
2. How is the cursor staying so well-aligned with the text such that it functions like the type of cursor in a word document? The cursor even aligns well with the text when I copy and paste the text. Is it the emmet dependency that's helping?

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="editor-holder">
    <ul class="toolbar">
        <li><a href="#" id="indent" title="Toggle tabs or spaces"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="fullscreen" title="Toggle fullscreen mode"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="scroller">
        <textarea class="editor allow-tabs">&lt;div class="Editable Textarea"&gt;
  &lt;h1&gt;This is a fully editable textarea which auto highlights syntax.&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;Type or paste any code in here...&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div&gt;

&lt;?php
  var simple = "coding";
?&gt;

&lt;script&gt;
  with = "Tab or double space functionality";
&lt;/script&gt;</textarea>
        <pre><code class="syntax-highight html"></code></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

**(S)CSS**

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(114, 195, 195);
}

.editor-holder{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -400px;
    left: 50%;
    background: #1f1f1f !important;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    
    &.fullscreen{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .toolbar{
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 3;
        padding: 8px;
        background: #afafaf;
        li{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        a{
            line-height: 20px;
            background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.6);
            color: grey;
            box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
            display: block;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            &:hover{
                background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.8);
            }
            &.active{
                background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.8);
                box-shadow: none;
            }
        }
        i{
            color: #565656;
            padding: 8px;
        }
    }
    
    textarea, code{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 450px;
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        top: 46px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 20px !important;
        line-height: 21px;
        position: absolute;
        font-family: Consolas,Liberation Mono,Courier,monospace;
        overflow: visible;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    textarea{
        background: transparent !important;
        z-index: 2;
        height: auto;
        resize: none;
        color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder{
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        }
        
        &:focus{
            outline: 0;
            border: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
    }

    code{
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;  
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;  
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    code{
        background: #1f1f1f !important;
        color: #adadad;

        .hljs {
            color: #a9b7c6;
            background: #282b2e;
            display: block;
            overflow-x: auto;
            padding: 0.5em
        }
        .hljs-number,
        .hljs-literal,
        .hljs-symbol,
        .hljs-bullet {
                color: #6897BB
        }
        .hljs-keyword,
        .hljs-selector-tag,
        .hljs-deletion {
                color: #cc7832
        }
        .hljs-variable,
        .hljs-template-variable,
        .hljs-link {
                color: #629755
        }
        .hljs-comment,
        .hljs-quote {
                color: #808080
        }
        .hljs-meta {
                color: #bbb529
        }
        .hljs-string,
        .hljs-attribute,
        .hljs-addition {
                color: #6A8759
        }
        .hljs-section,
        .hljs-title,
        .hljs-type {
                color: #ffc66d
        }
        .hljs-name,
        .hljs-selector-id,
        .hljs-selector-class {
                color: #e8bf6a
        }
        .hljs-emphasis {
                font-style: italic
        }
        .hljs-strong {
                font-weight: bold
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tabCharacter = "  ";
var tabOffset = 2;

$(document).on('click', '#indent', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    
    self.toggleClass('active');
    
    if(self.hasClass('active'))
    {
        tabCharacter = "\t";
        tabOffset = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        tabCharacter = "  ";
        tabOffset = 2;
    }
})

$(document).on('click', '#fullscreen', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    
    self.toggleClass('active');
    self.parents('.editor-holder').toggleClass('fullscreen');
});

/*------------------------------------------
    Render existing code
------------------------------------------*/
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    hightlightSyntax();
    
    emmet.require('textarea').setup({
    pretty_break: true,
    use_tab: true
    });
});




/*------------------------------------------
    Capture text updates
------------------------------------------*/
$(document).on('ready load keyup keydown change', '.editor', function(){
    correctTextareaHight(this);
    hightlightSyntax();
});


/*------------------------------------------
    Resize textarea based on content  
------------------------------------------*/
function correctTextareaHight(element)
{
  var self = $(element),
      outerHeight = self.outerHeight(),
      innerHeight = self.prop('scrollHeight'),
      borderTop = parseFloat(self.css("borderTopWidth")),
      borderBottom = parseFloat(self.css("borderBottomWidth")),
      combinedScrollHeight = innerHeight + borderTop + borderBottom;
  
  if(outerHeight < combinedScrollHeight )
  {
    self.height(combinedScrollHeight);
  }
}
// function correctTextareaHight(element){
//  while($(element).outerHeight() < element.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(element).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(element).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
//      $(element).height($(element).height()+1);
//  };
// }


/*------------------------------------------
    Run syntax hightlighter  
------------------------------------------*/
function hightlightSyntax(){
    var me  = $('.editor');
    var content = me.val();
    var codeHolder = $('code');
    var escaped = escapeHtml(content);
    
    codeHolder.html(escaped);
    
    $('.syntax-highight').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
}


/*------------------------------------------
    String html characters
------------------------------------------*/
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
             .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
             .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
             .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
             .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
             .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}


/*------------------------------------------
    Enable tabs in textarea
------------------------------------------*/
$(document).delegate('.allow-tabs', 'keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
        var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                                + tabCharacter
                                + $(this).val().substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again
        $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
        $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + tabOffset;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code in a snippet in the question itself. External liks are ok, but *only* in addition to include the code directly.

Comment: thanks and updated @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How does code and textarea elements stay aligned?
   They are aligned because in the CSS they both use the same style which outlines the positioning of both elements. They both use `position: absolute` and the same top and left properties so stay in the same position.
   See here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

   In terms of the z-axis you can see that code has a `z-index` of 1 while textarea has 2 so text area stays on top.
2. How is the cursor staying aligned with the text?
   There is no javascript acting on the cursor here. If you were to have any textarea in html the cursor would align with the text.